# MIPS-correspondence of the time complexity in assembly and high level language

Tags: assembly, time-complexity, mips

knowing that a one line of code in a high level language does not correspond to a one line assembly code and

Noting
that time complexity is dependent on the number of instructions executed relative
to the input size, how does this correspondence (partially) affect the computation
of time complexity of a given block of high-level language code in general?

Comment: It doesn't.  A big block of high-level code can sometimes compile to a few machine instructions, and sometimes a few high-level statements can take many machine instructions.  (Especially in languages higher level than C, where one statement can do soemthing to every element of an array and require a loop).

Comment: Also no, execution time is not proportional to the number of instructions executed.  Code with a lot of cache misses or other bottlenecks might run only 0.1 instructions per clock, but other code might run multiple instructions *per* clock, e.g. up to 4 per clock on [a superscalar MIPS r10000](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R10000) or x86 Skylake.  (Or close to 1 IPC on a simple pipelined in-order classic-RISC pipeline like early MIPS.)

Comment: Time complexity is always specified relative to a computational model. The same algorithm can have different time-complexities in different models. For example, the CMSP can be solved in polynomial time with an Alternation (ATM). The study of how these models time-classes relate is the main topic of Computational Theory. The High-level model and the low-level model are different models but they are polynomially related and so there is nothing really useful going on there (for a theorist).